# Can women bathe or dress in front of other women?

Tags: women, clothing, tznius-modesty

I recently asked if Noah's condemnation of his son seeing his ervah implies that men should hide ervah even from other male relatives:

[Should men hide ervah from other men according to Bereishith 9?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/129008/should-men-hide-ervah-from-other-men-according-to-bereishith-9)

What about women? Can they bathe with other women, or must they be alone when bathing or dressing? Would the answer differ depending on whether the other women were family members?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56273/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Does that answer imply that rules for tznius don't necessarily apply to women when they're just with other women (though the answer may be different for men with men)?

Comment: Tznius applies even when one is alone. Thus one should remain covered even in private, all the more so before others.

Comment: @N.T. To make sure I understand, a woman can obviously bathe alone, right? So whether or not tznius applies is not the issue. Can a woman only bathe when she is by herself, can she bathe with other women? If the latter, are there exceptions?

Comment: Obviously one can remove clothing for a necessary purpose, such as bathing. In days when people washed at bathhouses, that meant in the presence of others. Even men who go to the mikvah nowadays have the same situation.

Comment: @N.T. Oh, so for your comment, "Tznius applies even when one is alone. Thus one should remain covered even in private, all the more so before others," you weren't referring specifically to _bathing_ but rather were speaking _in general_, I assume. Bathing with multiple people is acceptable, even despite the lack of clothes, so long as the group that's bathing isn't mixed, then, correct?

Comment: Tznius is a mindset and way of life.