# What males can bathe together?

Tags: tznius-modesty, mikvah-ritual-bath, showering-bathing

Some questions on the site relate to restrictions on certain males bathing together:

- [close (male) relatives going to the mikvah together](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20639/close-male-relatives-going-to-the-mikvah-together)
- [Should men hide ervah from other men according to Bereishith 9?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/129008/should-men-hide-ervah-from-other-men-according-to-bereishith-9)

To ask a question that's broader than the first question above but more specific than the second, what males, in particular, are prohibited from bathing together, and which males are permitted? Based on the links above, it appears that a man can't bathe with his father, father-in-law, and brother-in-law.

What other categories are relevant? For example, while some might also avoid doing so with their brothers, is this a requirement? Outside these categories, is it acceptable for a man to bathe with all other types of males?